# Is the class of an object part of the value of that object in Python?

Tags: python, class, variables, attributes

My friend says that what the copy.copy() function does is copy the value *and class* of a variable to another variable. I said that the class was part of the value, but he doesn't believe so. The code:

```
harry = Animal('hippogriff')
```

He says that 'hippogriff' is the value of the object, not Animal('hippogriff'). Is this true?

Comment: The "value" of an object is not generally a well-defined concept. It's generally better to describe the functionality of `copy.copy` without reference to a "value".

Comment: It first and foremost depends on the contents of `Animal`'s constructor, but I think we can assume the boring `self.foo = foo` variant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`copy.copy()` will create a shallow copy of the *object*; it'll create a new instance of the type and copy across all attributes.

In this case, a new `Animal()` instance is created, and whatever attribute holds a reference to the string `hippogriff` is copied across to the new copy. If there are any mutable attributes on `harry` that are mutable (dictionaries, lists, other custom class instances) then the new copy will share a reference to these with `harry` and any changes are visible on both instances.

The `Animal()` instance is the actual 'value' here; but it is a compound object, and it's attributes are values in their own right.

For Python 'primitive' types such as `int` or `str`, which are not mutable, the object is itself the 'value' your friend refers to; there is no attribute on a `str` object that holds the string value. It is not a compound value, after all. But you shouldn't get hung up on the idea of 'value' here too much.

Call them objects instead. In Python everything is an object, objects have a type and many can have attributes, which refer to *other* objects. Even methods are objects in this respect; the `'hippogriff'` string has `.upper` and `.lower` attributes, both references to methods that you can call, and these methods are objects too. In Python, it is turtles all the way down!

Comment: So, in short, the class information *is* preserved although it is not usually called the "value".

Comment: Well, what I'm basically asking is if *everything* on the right side of the equals sign is the value. Oh, I see you've edited it! Thanks.

Comment: THanks for all this info! But very simply, what I'm trying to ask is what the stuff on the right side of the equals sign is called. Is it the value? The type? The object?

Comment: @JonathanSpirit: You have an *expression* there. All expressions result either in an object, or an exception is raised. Here, presumably, `Animal('hippogriff')` will produce an object.

Comment: So it's technically not even called the value of the variable? Just the expression? Like, the right side of `harry = 'hippogriff'` is an expression?

Comment: @JonathanSpirit: Once he expression has executed, `harry` is bound to an object. You can call that a value if you like.

Comment: @JonathanSpirit: I call it an object because *another* variable can refer to the same object; e.g. `ron = harry`. Now both `ron` and `harry` both refer to the same object.

Comment: But harry would be the value of ron, right? At least, the top level value? And Animal('hippogriff') would be the top level value of harry?

Comment: @JonathanSpirit: *value* is a very hazy term; many people coming from procedural languages (such as C) have different ideas about what constitutes a value, for example.

Comment: @JonathanSpirit: No, `ron` and `harry` are just variable names. They both refer to **one** object of type `Animal`, which may or may not have an attribute referring to the string `'hippogriff'`.

Comment: @JonathanSpirit: You can delete `ron` and `harry` would still refer to that object. Or you could delete `harry` instead and `ron` would still refer to the object. Or you could rebind both to different objects (`ron = None` and `harry = 1`) and then the object would be cleaned up automatically because nothing is referring to it anymore.

Comment: So, like the other answer said, the value is "anything stored in the per-instance dictionary of attributes for that object"? So, the value of ron would include Animal() and 'hippogriff' and an object and a class and many other things?

Comment: @JonathanSpirit: I see now that the [Python datamodel documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) does use the term *value*, where it is used to refer to the overall compound state of the object. `Animal('hippogriff')` is an object of type `Animal` and it's value is it's `__dict__` holding the attributes for that instance.

Comment: There we go, the overall compound state is what I want. Everything there from top level to bottom level, "anything stored in the per-instance dictionary of attributes for that object, and in any slots the object has". That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> He says that 'hippogriff' is the value of the object, not
>   Animal('hippogriff'). Is this true?

This is certainly wrong in general. For example consider:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.cointoss = random.choice(['heads', 'tails'])

harry = Animal('hippogriff')
```

Then what `copy.copy()` copies is not just `'hippogriff'`, it is also the result of the coin toss. Neither `'hippogriff'` nor `Animal('hippogriff')` adequately expresses the value of *this* object.

Roughly speaking, without reference to any particular programming language the "value" of an object is anything stored as per-instance data.

By that rough definition the class of an object *is* part of its value in Python. However the [Python data model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) (thanks to Martijn) distinguishes an object's "type" from its "value". Beware that in talking about type it admits in a footnote that what it says (that "type" cannot change) is not true, so you can't necessarily take this text as axiomatic.

Anyway you can *normally* consider that an object's type is separate from its value. In fact it is part of the object's mutable state and so for some rare purposes you might go against Python's definition and consider it part of the value. Fundamentally it's a matter of how you choose to define "value of an object", but if you go with the definition in the Python docs, which is reasonable when talking about Python, then they're separate things.

You might also consider whether or not an implementation of `copy.copy` has to do anything in particular to deal with the type of the object -- if it doesn't then clearly the type behaves like part of the value even though it's defined not to be part of it.

Comment: So taking in all technicalities, we can say that the value is everything? The type, everything stored in the per-instance dictionary of attributes. But my friend still says that the class is not part of the value. Is the class part of the value? And if so, is there a specific explanation?

Comment: @JonathanSpirit: I don't know what "taking in all technicalities" means in this case. If you accept the definition in the Python documentation of the "value of an object", then the type is not part of the value. There's a separate issue whether that's a helpful definition to use in the rare cases where the type is modified, but that issue is not about technicalities.

Comment: Never mind about all that first stuff. I'm just asking if the class is part of the value. Is the class the type? Or is it something else?

Comment: @JonathanSpirit: yes, the class is the type.

Comment: So it isn't part of the value. Got it! Thank you for all your help.